# Why in React componentWillReceiveprops fires before setState() in componentDidMount?

Tags: reactjs, lifecycle, setstate, react-props

I have been programming with React for a while now but I have never faced this annoying issue, in one of my components `componentWillReceiveProps` fires before `setState()` in `componentDidMount` gets executed. This causes several issues in my application.

I have a variable `this.props.flag` received from props which is going to be stored in the state of the component:

```
    componentDidMount() {
        if (!_.isEmpty(this.props.flag)) {

            console.log('Flag Did:', this.props.flag);

            this.setState({
                flag: this.props.flag
            },
                () => doSomething()
            );
    }
```

In my `componentWillReceiveProps` method the variable `this.state.flag` is going to be replaced just if it is empty or if it different from the value of `this.props.flag` (the checks are made by using the lodash library):

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    const { flag } = this.state;

    console.log('Flag Will:', !_.isEqual(flag, nextProps.flag), flag, nextProps.flag);

    if (!_.isEmpty(nextProps.flag) && !_.isEqual(flag, nextProps.flag)) {
            this.setState({
                flag: nextProps.flag,
            },
                () => doSomething()
            );
    }
}
```

Suppose that the prop `flag` in this case has always the same value and that `this.state.flag` is initialized to `undefined`. When I check the console log I see the following result:

```
Flag Did: true
Flag Will: true undefined true
```

Therefore when the code enters `componentWillReceiveProps` the value of `this.state.flag`is still `undefined`, that means has not been set yet by the `setState` in `componentDidMount`.

This is not consistent with React lifecycle or am I missing something? How can I avoid such behaviour?

Comment: `.setState()` is asynchronous. That's why it has a callback parameter (where you do the `doSomething()` call.)

Comment: @JJJ thanks for the answer. Even if .setState() is asynchronous, componentWillReceiveProps must wait for the execution of componentDidMount before firing, right?

Comment: Yes, but componentDidMount doesn't wait for asynchronous methods. It finishes execution long before `.setState()` resolves. (That's what "asynchronous" means.)

Comment: @JJJ got it, I understand what you mean, now everything is clear. I found a way to solve my issue by using props instead of state

Answer (score 1):

`ComponentWillReceiveProps()`  will be called in each update life-cycle caused by changes to props (parent component re-rendering). Since Javascript is synchronous you might have validate props sometimes to save app crashes. I've not totally understood the context of your app but what you can do is:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    const { flag } = this.state;

    if(!flag){
      return;, 
    }

    console.log('Flag Will:', !_.isEqual(flag, nextProps.flag), flag, nextProps.flag);

    if (!_.isEmpty(nextProps.flag) && !_.isEqual(flag, nextProps.flag)) {
            this.setState({
                flag: nextProps.flag,
            },
                () => doSomething()
            );
    }
}
```

You can return if state is undefined. It will be called again upon parent re-rendering. But this might not be use-case.

Anyways you should look into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37410633/lifecycle-componentwillreceiveprops-called-before-componentdidmount):

> But I can think of at least 1 (maybe theoretical) scenario where the order will reversed:
>
> Component receives props, and starts rendering. While component is
>   rendering, but has not yet finished rendering, component receives new
>   props. componentWillReceiveProps() is fired, (but componentDidMount
>   has not yet fired) After all children and component itself have
>   finished rendering, componentDidMount() will fire. So
>   componentDidMount() is not a good place to initialise
>   component-variables like your { foo: 'bar' }. componentWillMount()
>   would be a better lifecycle event. However, I would discourage any use
>   of component-wide variables inside react components, and stick to
>   design principles:
>
> all component variables should live in either state or props (and be
>   immutable) all other variables are bound by the lifecycle method (and
>   not beyond that)

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by user JJJ, given the asynchronous nature of `setState`, the check `if (!_.isEmpty(nextProps.flag) && !_.isEqual(flag, nextProps.flag))` in `componentWillReceiveProps` is executed before `setState` inside `componentDidMount` executes `flag: this.props.flag`. The order of the operations is:

1. Code enters `componentDidMount`.
2. Code executes setState in
   componentDidMount (`flag: this.props.flag` hasn't happened yet).
3. Code exits `componentDidMount`, `setState` in `componentDidMount` is
   still under execution (`flag: this.props.flag` hasn't happened yet).
4. Component receive new props, therefore enters
   `componentWillReceiveProps`.
5. The statement `if
   (!_.isEmpty(nextProps.flag) && !_.isEqual(flag, nextProps.flag))` in
   `componentWillReceiveProps` is executed (`this.state.flag` is still
   undefined).
6. Code finishes the execution of `setState` inside
   `componentDidMount` and sets `flag: this.props.flag` and executes
   `doSomething()`.
7. Code finishes the execution of `setState` inside
   `componentWillMount` and sets `flag: nextProps.flag` and executes
   `doSomething()`.

Given the asynchronous nature of `setState`, 6 and 7 could be executed in parallel and therefore we do not know which one will finish its execution first. `DoSomething()` in this case is potentially called at least 2 times when it must be called once instead.

In order to solve these issues, I changed my code this way:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)  {

if (!_.isEmpty(nextProps.flag) && !_.isEqual(this.props.flag, nextProps.flag)) {
        this.setState({
            flag: nextProps.flag,
        },
            () => doSomething()
        );
    }
}
```

This way I compare the new version(`nextProps`) with the old version(`this.props`) of the props, without waiting for the `flag` value to be stored in the component's state.