# Why does componentWillRecieveProps() is called before the page is re-rendered?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to re-render some values in my react-native app.
I have used `componentWillRecieveProps()` for that.
But, `componentWillRecieveProps()` is executed before re-render,setting wrong values in state.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    const {
        navigation
    } = nextProps;
    const flatListData = navigation.getParam("flatListData", "NO-DATA")
    console.log(flatListData)
    this.setState({
        dataSource: flatListData
    })
}
```

Comment: I think it was already handled in this post check it out here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37415405/10540998

Comment: `componentWillRecieveProps` will always executes before re-render, it's default behavior. Check this - https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear why you're requesting `navigation.getParam` in `componentWillReceiveProps`.  They're two very different things.  If this component is a react navigation route, then parameters will be set.   If this component is a child of another component then `componentWillReceiveProps` will be called with updated parameters when the parent component changes parameters.

Answer (score 4):

`componentWillRecieveProps` will always executes before re-render, it's default behavior.
[image]

You probably need `componentDidUpdate` which will execute after re-render.

---

**Note:** `componentWillRecieveProps` is replaced by `getDerivedStateFromProps`
[image]

[Reference](https://medium.com/@kartikag01/react-component-lifecycle-old-vs-new-32757aee5850) to this information.

Answer (score 2):

The component method `componentWillReceiveProps()` is deprecated in later react versions. 
You probably need `componentDidUpdate`.
Another problem I can see in the code is setting of state from props this is a common anti pattern and should be avoided. You can read more about better alternatives [here](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html)

Comment: Setting state is prohibited.What to do if we have requirement to change state of props on re-rendering

Comment: Good alternatives in the link: https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#recommendation-fully-uncontrolled-component-with-a-key